# Wrap text labels in bar chart 3d.js

Tags: javascript, text, charts, 3d, width

I'm trying to create a bar chart with data driven documents. But I ran into a problem that I can't fix by myself.

[image]

As you see in this image the text of the 3rd bar is overlapping the other text labels. I want to create a max-width so it will fit inside a box so it won't overlap the other labels. Is this possible? Here is my code:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 670 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range([ "#4a4a82", "#6b54b2", "#9269e1", "#b99fe3", "#d3d3d3"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var dataset = [
                {"State": "Vraag 1", "Helemaal eens": 20, "Eens": 10, "Niet eens, niet oneens": 20, "Oneens": 10, "Helemaal oneens": 10},
                {"State": "Vraag 2", "Helemaal eens": 20, "Eens": 10, "Niet eens, niet oneens": 20, "Oneens": 10, "Helemaal oneens": 10},
                {"State": "Zeer lange vraag om te kijken of het wordt afgehakt of niet", "Helemaal eens": 20, "Eens": 10, "Niet eens, niet oneens": 20, "Oneens": 10, "Helemaal oneens": 10},
                {"State": "Vraag 4", "Helemaal eens": 20, "Eens": 10, "Niet eens, niet oneens": 20, "Oneens": 10, "Helemaal oneens": 10},
                {"State": "Vraag 5", "Helemaal eens": 40, "Eens": 5, "Niet eens, niet oneens": 20, "Oneens": 10, "Helemaal oneens": 10}
            ]; 
  var ageNames = d3.keys(dataset[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; });

  dataset.forEach(function(d) {
    d.ages = ageNames.map(function(name) { return {name: name, value: +d[name]}; });
  });

  x0.domain(dataset.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
  x1.domain(ageNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d3.max(d.ages, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("foreignObject:g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .attr("width", 20)
      .append("xhtml:graphmatrixtext")
      .append("h5")
      .style("text-anchor", "begin");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".41em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("% Percentage");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; });

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(ageNames.slice())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width + 50)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width + 44)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; }); 

        var subject = svg.selectAll(".subject")
            .data(dataset)
          .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis");
```

The javascript that fixes the labels is this part:

```
  d3.svg.axis = function() {
    var scale = d3.scale.linear(), orient = d3_svg_axisDefaultOrient, tickMajorSize = 6, tickMinorSize = 6, tickEndSize = 6, tickPadding = 3, tickArguments_ = [ 10 ], tickValues = null, tickFormat_, tickSubdivide = 0;
    function axis(g) {
      g.each(function() {
        var g = d3.select(this);
        var ticks = tickValues == null ? scale.ticks ? scale.ticks.apply(scale, tickArguments_) : scale.domain() : tickValues, tickFormat = tickFormat_ == null ? scale.tickFormat ? scale.tickFormat.apply(scale, tickArguments_) : String : tickFormat_;
        var subticks = d3_svg_axisSubdivide(scale, ticks, tickSubdivide), subtick = g.selectAll(".tick.minor").data(subticks, String), subtickEnter = subtick.enter().insert("line", ".tick").attr("class", "tick minor").style("opacity", 1e-6), subtickExit = d3.transition(subtick.exit()).style("opacity", 1e-6).remove(), subtickUpdate = d3.transition(subtick).style("opacity", 1);
        var tick = g.selectAll(".tick.major").data(ticks, String), tickEnter = tick.enter().insert("g", "path").attr("class", "tick major").style("opacity", 1e-6), tickExit = d3.transition(tick.exit()).style("opacity", 1e-6).remove(), tickUpdate = d3.transition(tick).style("opacity", 1), tickTransform;
        var range = d3_scaleRange(scale), path = g.selectAll(".domain").data([ 0 ]), pathUpdate = (path.enter().append("path").attr("class", "domain"), 
        d3.transition(path));
        var scale1 = scale.copy(), scale0 = this.__chart__ || scale1;
        this.__chart__ = scale1;
        tickEnter.append("line");
        tickEnter.append("text");
        var lineEnter = tickEnter.select("line"), lineUpdate = tickUpdate.select("line"), text = tick.select("text").text(tickFormat), textEnter = tickEnter.select("text"), textUpdate = tickUpdate.select("text");
        switch (orient) {
         case "bottom":
          {
            tickTransform = d3_svg_axisX;
            subtickEnter.attr("y2", tickMinorSize);
            subtickUpdate.attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", tickMinorSize);
            lineEnter.attr("y2", tickMajorSize);
            textEnter.attr("y", Math.max(tickMajorSize, 0) + tickPadding);
            lineUpdate.attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", tickMajorSize);
            textUpdate.attr("x", 0).attr("y", Math.max(tickMajorSize, 0) + tickPadding);
            text.attr("dy", ".71em").style("text-anchor", "middle");
            pathUpdate.attr("d", "M" + range[0] + "," + tickEndSize + "V0H" + range[1] + "V" + tickEndSize);

            break;
          }
```

I would really really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this!

Answer (score 1):

[Mike Bostock himself has addressed this issue.](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321)

```
function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

vis.selectAll(".tick text")
  .call(wrap, 100);
```